# Ternary Operator (?:) based assignment avoids type check in C

Tags: c, gcc, implicit-conversion, conditional-operator, void-pointers

I am not able to understand why the compiler doesn't warn when assigning incompatible pointers through `(?:)` but does warn on direct assignment.

Compiler warns in this case:

> test.c: In function ‘main’: test.c:8:4: warning: assignment to
> ‘uint32_t *’ {aka ‘unsigned int *’} from incompatible pointer type
> ‘uint32_t **’ {aka ‘unsigned int **’} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
> 8 |  a = array;
> |    ^

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t *array[10], *a;
    a = array;
}
```

No warning in the following case:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int b = 8;
    uint32_t *array[10], *a;

    a = (b >= 8) ? array : malloc(8);
}
```

Environment:

```
Gcc version 9.3.0
Ubuntu 20.04
compilation cmd: gcc test.c -o test.out
```

Comment: Hint: what's the type of `malloc(8)`? What's the type of `(b >= 8) ? array : malloc(8)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of the expression `(b >= 8) ? array : malloc(8)` is `void*` (because `malloc(8)` has the type `void*`). You can see this by doing something non-sensical and having the compiler tell you:

```
((b >= 8) ? array : malloc(8)) * 5;
```

```
<source>:10:36: error: invalid operands to binary * (have 'void *' and 'int')
   10 |     ((b >= 8) ? array : malloc(8)) * 5;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
      |                       |
      |                       void *
```

`void*` can be implicitly converted to a pointer of any type, which is why the compiler doesn't complain when you assign that value to `a`.

Comment: To be a bit more precise: it is a specific rule of the ternary operator that it is allowed for one of the second and third operands to be a qualified or unqualified pointer to `void`  and the other to have any  object pointer type, in which case the result is an appropriately-qualified pointer to `void`.  This is not about `malloc` particularly, nor about the third operand *vs* the second.

Comment: Also, FWIW, I think this  rule was a miss.  It should go the other way, precisely because of cases like the one in the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger By going the other way, you think that the type of the ternary expression should be the non-`void*` type?

Comment: Yes, @Kevin, that would have been the better rule IMO.

Comment: I'd go farther than that, and require that the types of the second and third expressions match exactly, qualifiers and all. So for example, a NULL pointer or a void pointer would have to be cast to the appropriately qualified pointer type, or an error would be generated.

Comment: @kevin thanks for your answer, it doesn't say why the type of the given expression is void as is described by JohnBollinger but provides a nice trick to check that it is actually void. +1 for it.

Answer (score 7):

From the C Standard (6.5.15 Conditional operator)

> 6. ... otherwise, one operand is a pointer to void or a qualified version of void, in which case the result type is a pointer to an
>    appropriately qualified version of void.

The function `malloc` returns a pointer of the type `void *`. So the type of the expression with the conditional operator is `void *`. And a pointer of the type `void *` can be assigned to a pointer of any other object type.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
> pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the
> original pointer.

In fact you have

```
a = ( void * )(b >= 8 ? array : malloc(8) );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It surely answers the question but I don't think the second part of it is needed. The intention here is to write code so to avoid such cases where incompatible pointer assignments can happen without compiler warning about them. The (void *) cast isn't really the way to do it. Can you either remove it or provide a solution to it. Once done I can mark this answer accepted.

Comment: @Rajnesh The so-called second part  describes why there is no warning for ternary operator because a pointer of the type void * may be assigned to an object pointer to any other type. This part is important.

Comment: Okay got it now. Sorry, my bad. I misunderstood it.